# eslint JSX return error "expression expected"

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

```
card = (props) => (
  <div> efe </div>;
)
```

My esLINT send message "statement expected" 
How to fix this messege ?

Comment: YEP ! I EDIT code but erro still here .   Maybe I need rewrite .eslintrc  ?

Comment: Nah, I missed that you had a semicolon. Murat is right

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon e.g.

```
card = (props) => (
        <div> efe </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return an object you need to add parentheses:

```
card = (props) => (
    <div> efe </div>
);
```